# maven - maven central repo ignored in settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, http-proxy

I am trying to include the the maven central repo `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` in my settings.xml together with proxy settings to access it because the company nexus does not contain one of the more recent repositories that I need.

However when I do `mvn clean install` I get the following error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.the.repo.that.I.need: 
        Failure to find org.the.repo.that.I.need:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://company-nexus.com was cached in the local repository, 
        resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

So it tries to get the pom and jars from the `http://company-nexus.com` instead of `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`. How can I change that?

Here is my settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <localRepository>C:\Dev\m2</localRepository>


    <proxies>
        <proxy>
          <id>1</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>pass</password>
          <host>host</host>
          <port>port</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost|maven</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>

        <proxy>
          <id>1</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>https</protocol>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>pass</password>
          <host>host</host>
          <port>port</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost|maven</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus1</id>
                    <url>http://company-nexus.com</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus2</id>
                    <url>http://company-deploy-nexus.com</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus3</id>
                    <url>ttp://company-deploy-nexus2.com</url>
                </repository>

                <repository>
                    <id>maven-central</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>nexus1</id>
                    <url>http://company-nexus.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

</settings>
```

**EDIT**

It loads the correct settings.xml (in my `C:\Dev\m2` folder)

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.5.2\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\name\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.5.2\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\name\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Dev\m2
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Dev\m2
```

I will try again by putting the maven central repo into `.pom` instead of `settings.xml`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you already using a repository manager I recommend to configure if there instead of the settings.xml ...Apart from that why do you have configured so many repos in the default profile..usually you only need exactly two..and most important an mirrorOf:*..

Comment: Run `mvn -X` and check if maven is actually loading the settings from the correct file (i.e. check "Reading global settings" and "Reading user settings" lines).